# Bugs on highlighted menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

First, I apologize to not post my code right here.

I'm not sure this is a good idea since this is a kind of full project.
You can find [an online-version here](http://bartoman.fr/minimize/#filter-all)

My menu is stick to the top.
When users scroll, or chosse a section, the correct section will be highlighted in the menu. But if you click to a section, then scroll down / up, 2 menu secions will be highlighted.

So I would like to understand where  is the problem,  and so, how can i fix it .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happen because of 2 reason 1 is css issue and other on is js

1. CSS issue happen because of :focus Pseudo class styles you used. You apply :hover, :focus, :active and .active class same style. In your code I found this

   a, a:hover, a:focus, a:active, a.active {
   color: #f5c845;
   outline: 0 none;}

To solve this used following style after the above code snippets

```
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:focus{
color: #777;
border-bottom: none;}
```

2. To check your js issue can you please share your related js part for the one page scroll.